How to release unused IPs in OpenVPN Connect
I have a pair of OPNSense with OpenVPN servers set up for high availability with DUO. The  system and its components are up to date as of today.
Whenever I disconnect and connect to Wi-Fi quickly imitating enough packet drops that does the same thing to our clients with chunky internet connection I get a new IP and the old IP still stays behind. Needless to say for more than a couple of users the /24 network I set up for the VPN subnet gets exhausted pretty fast.
I tried to add the following one by one, and all of them to the client ovpn file: ip-win32 dynamic 10 (10 seconds for debugging only), persist-local-ip, persist-remote-ip, explicit-exit-notify 3 also set persist-remote-ip in the server configuration.
Can the server be set to release unused IP addresses if they aren't in use anymore? Or to reclaim the previously used IP in case of disconnect / reconnect if still available? Shouldn't one of the options I tried and mentioned above be doing something like that?
Or the only solution here is to set up a larger network like /16 even? The maximum number of users can be as high as 100 simultaneously. Even if they drop a handful of packages the IP pool will get exhausted faster than it frees itself up.
Additional information of the server that I just put in code formatting: TUN type, subnet topology, /24 network for the clients, split tunnel, reneg time 72000 (we don't want DUO lockouts), duplicate-cn, persist-remote-ip, route-nopull, UDP. I can give more information or details of the ovpn file too. Nothing too specific of course.

Well. After me (the left hand) didn't know what the right hand (my colleague) was doing, and going through the server settings, I realized there's an option now that wasn't there when I initially set up the server and that is "Username as CN" that allows unique CN to be used and the client won't send the CN from the certificate. I didn't check it earlier because it wasn't there, so my solution was to allow "duplicate-cn".
Bottom line is that checking "Username as CN" (only visible in advanced mode), removing "duplicate-cn", and adding "persist-remote-ip" in the "Options" dropdown did the trick. No matter if the connection is interrupted abruptly, unexpectedly, or using the disconnect button, the client will not get a brand new and still free IP address but will get back its old one. Downside is that only one device per user can connect simultaneously. Which is just fine in my environment.
